# why this AngularJs code is not working as i tried to run some perfect codes too but my browser doesn't run them also

Tags: angularjs

i'm running it using XAMPP but it's not working and showing output of **{{"Hello"+"you"}}** rather than **Hello you**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head ng-app="store">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script  type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js">
      </script>
      <script >
        var abc=angular.module('store',[]);
      </script> 
      <p>
        {{"Hello"+"you"}}
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing angular can do with `hello` and `you` until they are variable. Instead of try `1+2={{1+2}}` this and check

Comment: Yes, it can @varit05.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should create a `controller` in your **JS**, then you use it in your view.

You can do it setting the [**ng-controller**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) *directive*, as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('store', [])
      .controller('storeCtrl', function($scope) {

      });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="storeCtrl">
  <p>
    {{"Hello"+"you"}}
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: still the answer is {{"Hello"+"you"}}.

Comment: No, it isn't. Check it above. Just create your controller, then call it in your view using `ng-controller`.

Comment: yes!!! i just copy paste your code but it's displaying {{"Hello"+"you"}}